# add listener when iframe loads in javafx webview

Tags: javafx, iframe, webview, addeventlistener

I am trying to add listener when iframe in javafx webview is loaded and tried code below with no success. Any idea what's wrong or how to achieve same thing with different way.

```
if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {


                  EventListener ifloadedEventListener = new EventListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void handleEvent(Event ev) {
               System.out.println("in");
                      }
                    };

Document document = webEngine.getDocument();

                    HTMLIFrameElement iframeElement = (HTMLIFrameElement) document.getElementById("iframe");
                    Document iframeContentDoc = iframeElement.getContentDocument();
    ((EventTarget) iframeContentDoc ).addEventListener("load",floadedEventListener,false);
```

Thanks,
ASI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the event listener on the iFrame itself, not the document:

```
HTMLIFrameElement iframeElement = (HTMLIFrameElement) document.getElementById("iframe");
((EventTarget) iframeElement).addEventListener("load", floadedEventListener, false);
```